# Explicitly Logout the User programmatically in Websphere Portal 8 & redirect to the default login page

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-portal

I am a bit new to WS portal & have a requirement wherein on a specific scenario we want the user to logout & redirect him to the default portal login page.
I have tried to **invalidate the session** clear the cookies & do a response.sendRedirect as in **response.sendRedirect("/wps/myportal/")**; ,
but in vain.
Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure logout page using `wp_configservice`:

```
redirect.logout=true
redirect.logout.ssl=false
redirect.logout.url=protocol://host_name/logout_page
```

After configuring it, clicking on standard logout will redirect you to the specified page.

Comment: what is this wp_configservice?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JSF portlets, you can do something along the lines of the following - this should actually log the user session out as well as returning them to the default login page.

In reality you'll probably want to consider caching the initial context lookup by moving out the lookup code ( Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    PortletServiceHome stateMgrServiceHome = (PortletServiceHome) ctx.lookup("portletservice/com.ibm.portal.state.service.PortletStateManagerService");)

```
public void doLogOut() 
{
     String logoutUrl = generateLogoutURL(getPortletRequest(), getPortletResponse());
     redirectToUrl(logoutUrl);

}

    public String generateLogoutURL(PortletRequest request, PortletResponse response) throws RpmPortalException {
            final String methodName = "generateLogoutURL";
            String logoutURL = "";
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            PortletServiceHome stateMgrServiceHome = (PortletServiceHome) ctx.lookup("portletservice/com.ibm.portal.state.service.PortletStateManagerService");
            PortletStateManager stateMgr = null;

            LogoutActionAccessorController logoutCtrl = null;
            try {
                stateMgr = stateMgrService.getPortletStateManager(request, response);

                final URLFactory urlFactory = stateMgr.getURLFactory();
                EngineURL url = urlFactory.newURL(null);

                LogoutActionAccessorFactory logoutFct = (LogoutActionAccessorFactory) stateMgr.getAccessorFactory(LogoutActionAccessorFactory.class);
                logoutCtrl = logoutFct.newLogoutActionController(url.getState());

                logoutURL = url.writeDispose(new StringWriter()).toString();
            } catch (StateException e) {
                //do whatever you want

            } catch (IOException e) {
                //do whatever you want
            } finally {
                if (stateMgr != null) {
                    stateMgr.dispose();
                }

                if (logoutCtrl != null) {
                    logoutCtrl.dispose();
                }
            }

            return logoutURL;
        }
public void redirectToUrl(String url) {

        try {
            FacesContext context = getFacesContext();
            if (context != null) {
                context.getExternalContext().redirect(url);
                context.responseComplete();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Do whatever you want
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the standard configuration of Portal, directing a user to any page with `/wps/portal...` as the root instead of `/wps/myportal/...` will force the user to log out and the session to end.  So you could just create a friendly URL for your login page and redirect the user to `/wps/portal/friendlyLoginUrl`

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to what zargarf said, by default the following js is executed when you click on logout is mentioned below :

```
javascript:if(stproxy && stproxy.isLoggedIn){stproxy.login.logout();}
```